# Limiting Google Places search to places in a certain boundary around a coordinate or place

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am trying to implemente Google Places in my web form to get a delivery Address:

```
 <script>


      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });


        var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
        var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
        // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
        // bounds option in the request.
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
        autocomplete.setFields(
            ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          marker.setVisible(false);
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
            // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setVisible(true);

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
          infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
          infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
        // Autocomplete.
        function setupClickListener(id, types) {
          var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
          radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            autocomplete.setTypes(types);
          });
        }

        setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
        setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
        setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
        setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

        document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
            .addEventListener('click', function() {
              console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
              autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
            });
      }
    </script>


<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div>
    <div id="title">
      Please Enter Your Delivery Address
    </div>
    <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
      <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
      <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
      <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
    </div>
    <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
      <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="">
      <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict Bounds</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your delivery Address">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
```

I am completely new at this, and I would need your help to limit the place search to places inside a certain boundary, in this case to places near El Paso, Texas.

I don't know how to implement the search inside a boundary.

EDIT:

I don't really need the map to be shown, I do only need to get an address, but in this case, the map isn't visible, and I guess it should.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a circle with certain radius and get its latlng bounds

```
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({ center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), radius: 30000 })
                var options = {
          bounds: circle.getBounds(),
          componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'},
        strictBounds: true
        };

//I have added componentRestriction which you can omit
```

pass the `options` parameter to your autocomplete object like this:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
(document.getElementById('yourinputid')),
             options);
```